# SpriteKit - Quick touches cause wrong behaviour

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touch

I am currently working at a sidescroller game, in which the jump height depends on how long the player presses the right half of the screen. 
Everything works just fine, except if the user touches the screen quickly. This causes the jump to be as big as possible.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a problem with the way SpriteKit works? 
How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: Here are all the methods handling touches in my game:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    for touch in touches
    {
        swiped = false

        let location = touch.location(in: cameraNode)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.065)
        {
            if self.swiped == false
            {
                if location.x < 0
                {
                    self.changeColor()
                }
                else
                {
                    self.jump()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: cameraNode)

            if location.x > 0
            {
                // Right
                thePlayer.endJump()
            }
    }
}
```

And then there is also a gesture recognizer handling swiping left and right, with the following handlers:

```
    @objc func swipedRight()
{
        if walkstate != .walkingRight
        {
            walkstate = .walkingRight
        }
        else
        {
            boost(direction: 0)
        }

        swiped = true
}

@objc func swipedLeft()
{

        if walkstate != .walkingLeft
        {
            walkstate = .walkingLeft
        }
        else
        {
            boost(direction: 1)
        }

        swiped = true
}
```

Hopefully this is enough to describe the problems. The code above is everything I am doing to handle touches.

Comment: Depends entirely on the logic you have written to handle touches. How does your game react to touches?

Comment: You will need to show the code you are using before anyone can say what the cause of the issue is.

Comment: I added all the code I am using to handle touches. Hopefully this will help you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was, that I am using a **DispatchQueue** command to call the jumping method after a short delay, in case the user swiped and not tapped. As a result the **touchesEnded** method gets called before the jump has even started and thus can not be stopped anymore.

To solve this problem I added a boolean variable which is set to true as soon as the player touches the screen and set to false whenever the users finger leaves the screen. In order to jump this variable has to be set to true and thereby the character will not jump after a quick touch anymore.

Comment: For time related actions, you should use `SKActions`, rather than `GCD`. `GCD` doesn't respect the game loop and if a game goes into a background (eg. a player receives a phone call), the game won't be properly paused... Search about all this, there are few posts that are explaining the issue.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I used `GCD` because I just wanted to wait for the user input, while not interfering with the game loop. Should I still use an action? I thought if I use a action the hole game would be paused, but I only want the code to be executed in the background after a short delay.

Comment: @Whirlwind I tried it your way, and it works just fine, so thanks again.